# Ctrl + Shift + C doesn't copy from terminal

Tags: zsh, kali-linux

I have an msi ms-14c4 laptop and I'm running Kali linux with zsh on it.
The problem is when I try to copy text from the terminal using the `left-ctrl`+`left-shift`+`c` shortcut, nothing is copied to the clipboard. However, when I use `right-ctrl`+`left-shift+c` or `left-ctrl`+`right-shift`+`c` (when `ctrl` and `shift` are opposite sides) it does work for some reason.

`ctrl`+`c` works fine, `shift`+`c` also works fine, it's just when I press them together it doesn't work.

I tried using the `showkey` command to log to the console all of the keystrokes, and I had noticed that `ctrl` and `shift` key are logged, but the `c` key isn't when both `shift` and `ctrl` are held.

I have looked at the terminal settings and the shortcut seems fine there.
I had also tried using different terminal but it still didn't work.

Any help or debugging tips will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using a different keyboard?

Comment: Your ouput of `xmodmap`?

Comment: @MarlonRichert it works fine with a different keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your comment, the problem is in your keyboard. Try the following:

1. Update your driver.
2. If that doesn’t help, take your laptop to a certified service station for repairs.
3. If they don’t find anything broken, you can try to get a replacement keyboard installed for free, on the grounds that it’s a manufacturing error.
4. Failing that, you could investigate if it’s possible to install an off-brand keyboard that doesn’t exhibit this problem.